# Controller Connection Issue!

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, games, emulators

This is copied from Reddit I'm just trying to find an answer to my problem. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on an old, Dell Latitude E6400 (it runs pretty well). I play a few various emulators and I prefer to use a controller (wired xbox one). It was running fine until the latest update (a day or two ago). Now, it will only work if it is plugged in when the system boots,. Otherwise, the system won't recognize it or power it (there is a little white indicator light that lights up when connected to the computer) . Is there anything that can be done to fix this?

Update: Just tried using the controller after boot and it Ubuntu isn't recognizing the controller at all it just makes the little led light up. It worked fine until I updated everything.

Update 2: Ran "lsusb" and its being recognized by Ubuntu but still isn't working. I checked the controller on a different emulator after boot and it does work (so the initial problem I was having was just the emulator) but if I unplug the controller and try to plug it back in it won't work, I have to restart the system. but it is still recognized in "lsusb"

Update 3: I also ran "sudo modprobe xpad" and it did nothing. Forgot to mention that.

Update 4: Last one I promise, I plugged in a different controller (still an xbox one) and it works just fine. I am beyond stumped by this. Also, I plugged in the controller to a Windows computer and it worked just fine. This is just crazy to me. It worked no problem up until a couple days ago. I'm probably going to just give up trying to figure this out if no one has any ideas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Output of `lsusb`? Output of `dmesg` as you connect the controller?

Comment: Output of lsusb is; Bus 007 Device 004: ID 0e6f:02df Logic3 PDP Wired Controller for Xbox Series X - Red Camo

Output dmesg; [ 4151.575647] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4151.575655] usb 7-1: Product: PDP Wired Controller for Xbox Series X - Red Camo
[ 4151.575661] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Performance Designed Products
[ 4151.575667] usb 7-1: SerialNumber: 000038CED3F1E5EC
[ 4151.580461] input: Generic X-Box pad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input27

I hope thats what you were looking for. I'm fairly new to Ubuntu.

Comment: It's useless in a comment. Please add it to your question, and use `{}` to format the block as code

Comment: The `lsusb` should be after you've connected the dubious controller. Take `dmesg` immediately after it's connected and there should be a text if messages relevant to you having just plugged it in

Comment: Ok, I've added screen shots of the terminal after running both commands. sorry misunderstood.

Comment: No. Please don't post screenshots. They're unreadable